# How to mosaic two tif data by gdal_merge

Tags: gdal-merge

my method is as follows(Some paths have been omitted.)

```
 enter code here gdal_merge.py F:\test_data\LC81210402013278LGN00_B1.TIF F:\test_data\LC81220402013285LGN00_B1.TIF -o F:\mo529.tif
```

but failed,The error is as follows：

How should I do?

Comment: So what was the error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

1. I solved it myself.Maybe I'm so stupid. My gdal_merge from GitHub
   (https://github.com/geobox-infrastructure/gbi-client/blob/master/app/geobox/lib/gdal_merge.py).
   But it didn't work.
2. Finally, I found the correct 'gdal_merge' from the path of Gdal.Like that

> F：\Gdal\bin\gdal\python\scripts

And there are many other tools in the file.   I think it may be helpful for a layman.